# When I use search filter Recycler View gives wrong Position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implemented my `CustomAdapter.kt` with `search filter` as follows.

```
class CustomAdapter(public val context: Context, private val countriesResponse: CountriesResponse) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var countryFilterList = CountriesResponse()

init {
    countryFilterList = countriesResponse
}


class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var image: ImageView
    var cv_tv_country_name: TextView

    init {
        
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_iv_country_flag)
        cv_tv_country_name = itemView.cv_tv_country_name

    }
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.flag_list, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryFilterList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Glide.with(context).load(countryFilterList[position].countryInfo.flag).into(holder.image)
    
    //Here I am setting onClickListener for the items clicked on recycler view
    
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
         
        //With the help of intent I am starting new activity with taking the position of that item
        
        val intent =
            Intent(context, CountryWiseDataActivity::class.java).putExtra("position", position)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    holder.cv_tv_country_name.text = countryFilterList[position].country
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter(){
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val charSearch = constraint.toString()
            if (charSearch.isEmpty()){
                countryFilterList = countriesResponse
            } else {
                val resultList = CountriesResponse()
                for (row in countriesResponse){
                    if (row.country.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains(charSearch.toLowerCase(
                            Locale.ROOT))){
                        resultList.add(row)
                    }
                }
                countryFilterList = resultList
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = countryFilterList
            return filterResults
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            countryFilterList = results?.values as CountriesResponse
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }
}
```

}

In my Activity I have implemented below for search Filter.

```
search_countries.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            countryAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })
```

This above code works fine and it search the countries as well properly. But when I click the country it should open an another activity `CountryWiseDataActivity`for that same country.

I have implemented `CountryWiseDataActivity.kt` as follows.

```
class CountryWiseDataActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var viewModel: CountriesViewModel
private lateinit var countryDetailsRepository: CountryDetailsRepository


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_country_wise_data)

    val apiService: ApiService = ApiClient.getClient()
    countryDetailsRepository = CountryDetailsRepository(apiService)

    viewModel = getViewModel()
    val intent = getIntent()
    val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)//{<- The position of every country with the help of intent

    viewModel.countryDetails.observe(this, Observer {
            tv_country.text = it.get(position).country
            tv_country_cases.text = it.get(position).cases.toString()
            tv_country_active.text = it.get(position).active.toString()
            tv_country_critical.text = it.get(position).critical.toString()
            tv_country_recovered.text = it.get(position).recovered.toString()
            tv_country_today_cases.text = it.get(position).todayCases.toString()
            tv_country_today_deaths.text = it.get(position).todayDeaths.toString()
            tv_country_total_deaths.text = it.get(position).deaths.toString()
    })
}

private fun getViewModel(): CountriesViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return CountriesViewModel(countryDetailsRepository) as T
        }
    })[CountriesViewModel::class.java]

}
}
```

But When I search the country in search bar and click on country, then the data displays is only for the `position 0`. If I don't use search bar for searching countries and simply click on the country for data it gives correct data for every position.

I am stuck here that how to correct this code, so that I can search countries & on clicking it gives the correct data of that particular country?

Comment: Try use index to filter the list, this is a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531095/i-have-recyclerview-with-searchview-how-to-send-details-data-about-item-i-search/64556112#64556112

Answer (score 0):

You are getting country list from api.But you are  filtering countries list and storing it `locally`. That filtered list is within your activity itself.But while clicking filtered list item you are just passing the position to another activity.But in next activity you are calling api and getting the `full list` not `filtered list`.that's why you are facing this problem.To solve this issue there are two options.
1.you should pass clicked `country object` to next activity instead of passing `position`.
or
2.you should send `filtered list with position` to next activity.