# how to filter the recycler view using search view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

Can anyone help me. I'm having a problem on filtering the recycler view, I have a Search View at the top of my app and I want to filter the tricycle number only. I have 4 Array list of String and each of them have values. The problem is I don't know how to only filter the tricycle number I try a lots of things but I really don't know, Can you help me?. Here's my Driver List Adapter code

```
    public class DriverListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DriverListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable{


private ArrayList<String> mNickNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mPhoneNumber = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mTricycleNumber = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

private List<String> mNickNamesAll;
private List<String> mPhoneNumberAll;
private List<String> mTricycleNumberAll;
private List<String> mImageUrlsAll;


public DriverListAdapter(BookingActivity bookingActivity, ArrayList<String> nickNames, ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers, ArrayList<String> mTricycleNumber, ArrayList<String> images){
    //this.driverList = driverList;
    this.context = bookingActivity;
    this.mNickNames = nickNames;
    this.mPhoneNumber = phoneNumbers;
    this.mTricycleNumber = mTricycleNumber;
    this.mImageUrls = images;
    //this.mUserID = userId;

    mNickNamesAll = new ArrayList<>(nickNames);
    mPhoneNumberAll = new ArrayList<>(phoneNumbers);
    mTricycleNumberAll = new ArrayList<>(mTricycleNumber);
    mImageUrlsAll = new ArrayList<>(images);

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //return null;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
    //return new ViewHolder(view);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DriverListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.tvNickName.setText(mNickNames.get(position));
    holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(mPhoneNumber.get(position));
    holder.tvTricycleNumber.setText(mTricycleNumber.get(position));
    holder.tvLine.setText("_____________________________________");


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bookDialog(mTricycleNumber.get(position), mNickNames.get(position));
        }
    });

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to Driver Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DriverProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_url", mImageUrls.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("tricycle_number", mTricycleNumber.get(position));
            context.startActivity(intent);
            //finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNickNames.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(mNickNamesAll);
            filteredList.addAll(mPhoneNumberAll);
            filteredList.addAll(mTricycleNumberAll);
            filteredList.addAll(mImageUrlsAll);
        } else {
            for (String nicknames: mNickNamesAll) {
                if (nicknames.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredList.add(nicknames);
                }
            }
            for (String phonenumbers: mPhoneNumberAll){
                if (phonenumbers.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredList.add(phonenumbers);
                }
            }
            for (String tricyclenumber: mTricycleNumberAll){
                if (tricyclenumber.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredList.add(tricyclenumber);
                }
            }
            for (String imageUrl: mImageUrlsAll){
                if (imageUrl.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredList.add(imageUrl);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filteredList;
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mTricycleNumber.clear();
        mNickNames.clear();
        mPhoneNumber.clear();
        mImageUrls.clear();

        mNickNames.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) results.values);
        mPhoneNumber.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) results.values);
        mTricycleNumber.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) results.values);
        mImageUrls.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) results.values);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private CircleImageView imageView;
    private TextView tvNickName;
    private TextView tvPhoneNumber;
    private TextView tvTricycleNumber;
    private TextView tvLine;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        tvNickName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nick_name);
        tvPhoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_number);
        tvTricycleNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tricycle_number);
        tvLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_line);
    }
}

private void bookDialog(final String tricyclenumber, final String tricyclenickname){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context
    );
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_24);
    builder.setTitle("Book Tricycle:");
    builder.setMessage("Tricycle Number " + tricyclenumber + " You What To Book This Tricycle?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //firestore insert data!
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to Book Transaction Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, BookTransactionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tricycle_number", tricyclenumber);
            intent.putExtra("tricycle_nickname", tricyclenickname);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}}
```

Here's the code of the Search View.

```
     svSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            driverListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531095/i-have-recyclerview-with-searchview-how-to-send-details-data-about-item-i-search/64556112#64556112